# IOException parsing XML document

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

```
    Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/web-inf/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/web-inf/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">


  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>web-inf/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

Application can't find dispatcher-servlet.xml. I suppose that dispatcher-servlet.xml is in correct catalog.

[image: catalogs]

I have been searching stackOverFlow for a long time, but it doesn't help. 
This is very strange because it works on 
Windows, this problem appears on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I am more used to writing WEB-INF in uppercase. Anyways try defining the location with a leading slash like this :

```
<param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
```

Comment: When i changed web-inf to WEB-INF i have other problems: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'

Comment: Then it would seem you're making progress. I would advise to keep the forward slash and dig into your dispatcher-servlet.xml. The userService bean is missing. Either describe this bean in dispatcher-servlet.xml or component-scan it by annotating it @Service and adding a <component-scan /> element in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: i have    <context:component-scan base-package="com.catty.app" /> in dispatcher-servlet.xml, also all beans are annotated (for example userService has @Service). This project works on windows well (i have problem on mac), so I don't have any problems with Java code. I have a problem with configuration

Comment: Then it could have something to do with the classpath of your application on Mac. I don't know which build system you're using, but I guess you have a classes directory somewhere. Check that the class file exists for the userService bean.